# Problem with treetop grammar, not matching all options

Tags: ruby, lisp, treetop

I am writing a small, really simple lisp parser in ruby with the treetop gem just to experiment with it. However, it is not really working out how I want it to, and the documentation is pretty poor so it's hard to understand what I am doing wrong. Currently, the grammar can match both a symbol and a boolean, but not a number. However, when I switch the order in the atom rule, for example to bool /  number / symbol, it still matches for the first two, but not the last one. Is there a limitation in the treetop gem that means you can only have two options in a rule? Also, something like '(3)' still does not parse.

My grammar is as follows:

```
grammar Lisp
 rule expression
   atom / list
 end

 rule atom
   symbol / bool / number
 end

 rule number
   [0-9]*
 end

 rule bool
   'T' / 'F'
 end

 rule symbol
  [a-zA-Z]*
 end

 rule list
   '(' expression* ')'
 end    
end
```

I am testing it as they showed in the tutorial, with:

```
parser = LispParser.new
if parser.parse('T')
  puts "Success"
else
  puts "Fail"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you defined the rules `number` and `symbol` they always match (because `*` means "zero or more" and you can always find zero of something). This means that if you try to parse "42", the parser first successfully matches the rule `symbol` against the empty string at the beginning and then expect no further input.

To fix this simply replace `*` with `+`.

Comment: @bennybdbc: Also, the way the `atom` rule is defined now, it will never match a boolean, because `T` and `F` also match the regexp in the `symbol` rule, so they will always be parsed as a `symbol`.

Comment: @Jorg - Yes thanks I noticed that earlier. I changed the code in my program, I just didn't think to edit the question.